# String from command prompt

Tags: c, string, function, command-line

I'm trying to pass my arguments using the command prompt.

There are
3 different types can be passed to my program: int, char, string. It works correctly for ints and char, but i'm getting seg faulted, in the case if i'm passing strings.

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "MergeSort.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
if (argc > 2){
    if (strcmp(argv[1], "int") == 0){
        cmp_t cmp = CompareInt;
        int arr[argc - 2];
        for(int i = 2; i < argc; i++) sscanf (argv[i], "%d", &arr[i - 2]);;
        merge_sort(arr,  argc - 2, sizeof(int), cmp);
        for(int i = 0; i < argc - 2; i++) printf("%i ", arr[i]);
    }
    else if(strcmp(argv[1], "char") == 0){
        cmp_t cmp = CompareChar;
        char arr[argc - 2];
        for(int i = 2; i < argc; i++) sscanf (argv[i], "%c", &arr[i - 2]);;
        merge_sort(arr,  argc - 2, sizeof(char), cmp);
        for(int i = 0; i < argc - 2; i++) printf("%c ", arr[i]);
    }
    else{
        cmp_t cmp = CompareStr;
        char* arr[argc - 2];
        for(int i = 2; i < argc; i++) sscanf (argv[i], "%s", arr[i - 2]);
        merge_sort(arr,  argc - 2, sizeof(char*), cmp);
        for(int i = 0; i < argc - 2; i++) printf("%s ",arr[i]);
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You did not allocate storage for your strings.  You just used raw, uninitialised pointers and started writing to whatever random locations they pointed at.

Comment: What does the debugger show you when you step through that section of the code?

Comment: `char* arr[argc - 2];`. need to allocate memory for each of the strings. Each of those elements are currently uninitialised pointers. `sscanf` does not allocate memory for you.

Comment: Alternatively, you can just store the pointers already available in `argv` without allocating or copying strings.

Comment: @kaylum So what is the proper way to allocate memory?

Comment: `arr[i-2] = strdup(argv[i]);`. Or just copy the pointer not the contents as you don't really need to modify the string: `arr[i-2] = argv[i]`

Comment: @paddy Can i just replace it with `merge_sort(argv + 2,  argc - 2, sizeof(char*), cmp);`?

Comment: No please don't chain questions like this while we're here.  Take that advice, go and learn, and then come back if you are having difficulty.  Because even if we help you deal with the strings, the next thing you'll ask is why the merge sort isn't working, and we'll say it's because you need a string version of your `cmp` function, and you'll ask "how do I do that", and we go round and round in circles.

Comment: @KirillVishnyakov yes you could do that, but it's not great style to modify argv.  You can copy the pointers into your local array without any worries.

Comment: @kaylum Thanks! Now it works.

Comment: @paddy Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can simply copy the pointers from `argv` to `arr` like : `arr[i-2] = argv[i]`;

The second way is to allocate memory for the strings.